# Is using a database-level MD5 function a bigger security risk than an application level function?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I've got a chunk of code that validates a user's username and password, which goes something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE 
    username='{$_POST['username']}' AND 
    password=MD5('{SALT}{$_POST['password']}')";
```

Is this any more/less secure than doing it like this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM user 
WHERE 
    username='{$_POST['username']}' AND 
    password='".md5(SALT.$_POST['password'])."'";
```

Regardless of where/if escaping is done, is the first method vulnerable to sql injection attacks? Would the answer be the same for other database engines besides MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking about injection, both ways are secure, if you properly escape variables.

The first case will be more vulnerable, if you use complete query logging, and so the password will appear as plain text.

Besides, if your system is affected by some virus that works as proxy between your script and database, it'll be able to catch your password.

One last problem that you may encounter (quite rarely, in fact), is when the system is inflicted with a virus, that reads sensible data from memory.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That's an interesting point. How common is query logging? It seems like it would be a horrifically bad idea to me, especially for personal information.

Comment: It's quite common, especially if you're using some third-party server. Anything may be running at an unknown side. You should make sure they provide documents, that clearly state security of your personal data, as well as ability to withstand malicious executables. Not being paranoiac, of course =) plain cautious

Comment: By the way, they don't have to log ALL queries, but only those that have either of MD5, SHA, PASSWORD, or any of these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use prepared statements instead **and** have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks).

Comment: I'm curious though, If the input wasn't escaped properly, would entering `') OR 1=1;--` allow a login in the first example? My gut says it would, but I don't know that much about DB internals.

Comment: Yes, because the password handling part (i.e. everything past the ") AND") would never even get executed.

Comment: @Andrew Medico - If that was in the password field, that is. So, it would end up looking like `password=MD5('SALT') OR 1=1;--password')`

Answer (score 1):

Oh god, please tell me you're doing some type of `mysql_escape_string` or `mysql_real_escape_string` or AT LEAST `addslashes` or `addcslashes` to any `$_POST` variables **before** you insert them into a raw MySQL statement?

I think the most secure way to do this is to:

a) use `filter_var` or `preg_replace` to get rid of extraneous characters from the $_POST['username']

b) `SELECT` the row by the username from MySQL (also grabbing the digested password)

c) compare the message digested version of the password from the `$_POST` to that of the retrieved row (assuming you don't leave your password cleartext) in your application code, not in the SQL statement

If you do it this way, there's only 1 possible place for injection (username), and it's pretty impossible when you're doing a `preg_replace( '/\W/', '', $_POST['username'] )` which removes anything not A-Za-z0-9_- (or change to your username whitelist of characters).

However, if you're doing rock-solid proper sanitization, it really doesn't matter where you do your comparison.  Theoretically, though, I'd allow for the least possible interaction with user input and raw SQL statements (i.e. only `SELECT`ing by username and comparing outside of your DB).

Answer (score 1):

To start off with MD5 is prevent to be an insecure algorithm and should never be used for passwords. You should use a staled sha256 and most databases do not have this function call.  But even if the database did I think its a bad idea.  Not a very bad idea,  but its best to keep as few copies of your password around.  Often the database can be on a completely different machine,  and if that machine where compromised then the attacker could obtain clear text passwords by looking at the quires.    In terms of SQL Injection,  there is no difference in security and judging by your queries you should be more worried about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

> Regardless of where/if escaping is done, is the first method vulnerable to sql injection attacks?

SQL injection will not occur if proper escaping and sanitizing takes place

> Would the answer be the same for other database engines besides MySQL?

I think you should look more at the expense taken to perform one action over another.  The first method would take less time to execute than the second method, ceteris paribus.